# Connecting from php to mysql in Docker

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, phpmyadmin

I am starting with docker and have some problems to make the right config.
The Framework need a script to make the backend working. 
This needs a sql connection. I found a way to make phpmyadmin working, but the script can't connect the mysql database.
If someone with more Docker comprehension can give me a tip if something is wrong.

```
myhomepage-mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: myhomepage-mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=MyHomepage
    - MYSQL_USER=homepage_admin
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin123

myhomepage-webserver:
  image: phpdockerio/nginx:latest
  container_name: myhomepage-webserver
  volumes:
      - ..:/var/www/myhomepage
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  links:
   - myhomepage-php-fpm

myhomepage-php-fpm:
  build: .
  dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
  container_name: myhomepage-php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ..:/var/www/myhomepage
    - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
  links:
    - myhomepage-mysql

myhomepage-phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: myhomepage-phpmyadmin
    environment:
        PMA_USER: root
        PMA_PASSWORD: toor
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    ports:
        - "8181:80"
    volumes:
       - /sessions
    links:
      - myhomepage-mysql:mysql
```

Second problem is that phpmyadmin give this message:

```
 Your PHP MySQL library version 10.1.20-MariaDB differs from your MySQL server version 5.7.17. This may cause unpredictable behavior.
```

Can i access phpmyadmin from http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin not from http://localhost:8181/ ?

Comment: First of all you should link mysql to phpmyadmin. Take a look at this https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/ Second, you can not use `..` as a host-src in `volumes` Take a look at this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems

Comment: @AstraSerg When i link mysql to phpmyadmin than i'll have this error: ERROR: Circular dependency between myhomepage-mysql and myhomepage-phpmyadmin

My "links:- myhomepage-mysql:mysq"l is the same like" --link mysql_db_server:db" or not?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this config work:

```
project-nginx:
  container_name: project-webserver
  image: nginx:latest
  volumes:
        - ..:/var/www/project
        - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - ./nginx/phpmyadmin.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
  ports:
     - 80:80
  links:
    - project-php
    - project-phpmyadmin

project-php:
  build: .
  dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
  container_name: project-php
  expose:
    - 9000
  volumes:
    - ..:/var/www/project
    - ./php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
  links:
    - project-mysql

project-mysql:
  image: mysql
  container_name: project-mysql
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=project
    - MYSQL_USER=project_admin
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin123

project-phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  container_name: project-phpmyadmin
  environment:
        - "PMA_HOST: project-mysql"
        - "PMA_USER : root"
        - "PMA_PASSWORD: toor"
  links:
    - project-mysql:db
  volumes:
    - /sessions
    - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
```